# Dataframe how to update a column based many str values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am creating a small financial management program which imports my transactions from CSV into Python. I want to assign values to a new column **'category'** based on strings found in the **'details'** column. I can do it for one, but my question is how do I do it if I had a huge list of possible strings? For example `str.contains('RALPHS')` will replace that column value with **'groceries'**, and so on.

For example, below I have a list of strings:

`dining = ['CARLS', 'SUBWAY', 'DOMINOS']`

and if either of those strings is found in my series, then it will update the respective category series to be 'dining'.

Here is a small run-able example below.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    [-68.23 , 'PAYPAL TRANSFER'],
    [-12.46, 'RALPHS #0079'],
    [-8.51, 'SAVE AS YOU GO'],
    [25.34, 'VENMO CASHOUT'],
    [-2.23 , 'PAYPAL TRANSFER'],
    [-64.29 , 'PAYPAL TRANSFER'],
    [-7.06, 'SUBWAY'],
    [-7.03, 'CARLS JR'],
    [-2.35, 'SHELL OIL'],
    [-35.23, 'CHEVRON GAS']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['amount', 'details'])
df['category'] = np.nan
str_xfer = 'TRANSFER'
df['category'] = (df['details'].str.contains(str_xfer)).astype(int)
df['category'] = df['category'].replace(
                                                            to_replace=1,
                                                            value='transfer')

df

    amount  details             category
0   -68.23  PAYPAL TRANSFER     transfer
1   -12.46  RALPHS              0
2   -8.51   SAVE AS YOU GO      0
3   25.34   VENMO CASHOUT       0
4   -2.23   PAYPAL TRANSFER     transfer
5   -64.29  PAYPAL TRANSFER     transfer
6   -7.06   SUBWAY              0
7   -7.03   CARLS JR            0
8   -2.35   SHELL OIL           0
9   -35.23  CHEVRON GAS         0
```

Thanks much.

Comment: Could you add some more examples of your possible strings, so we can reproduce an answer for you

Comment: HI Erfan, I have added some more strings for a better example.

Comment: I already showcased with more strings to search for, see my answer with `str_xfer = ['TRANSFER', 'RALPHS', 'CASHOUT']`. In this case it get's all these values from the the `details` column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have one value, we can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['category'] = df['details'].str.extract(f'({str_xfer})')
```

```
   amount          details  category
0  -68.23  PAYPAL TRANSFER  TRANSFER
1  -12.46     RALPHS #0079       NaN
2   -8.51   SAVE AS YOU GO       NaN
3   25.34    VENMO CASHOUT       NaN
4   -2.23  PAYPAL TRANSFER  TRANSFER
5  -64.29  PAYPAL TRANSFER  TRANSFER
```

---

If you have **multiple** strings to match, we have to delimit your strings first by `|`, which is the *or* operator in regular expressions.

```
str_xfer = ['TRANSFER', 'RALPHS', 'CASHOUT']
str_xfer = '|'.join(str_xfer)

df['category'] = df['details'].str.extract(f'({str_xfer})')
```

```
   amount          details  category
0  -68.23  PAYPAL TRANSFER  TRANSFER
1  -12.46     RALPHS #0079    RALPHS
2   -8.51   SAVE AS YOU GO       NaN
3   25.34    VENMO CASHOUT   CASHOUT
4   -2.23  PAYPAL TRANSFER  TRANSFER
5  -64.29  PAYPAL TRANSFER  TRANSFER
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I would be able to use this method to extract these details and then use these strings to further classify, right? So, from your example, into a list I can extract str_bank = ['TRANSFER', 'VENMO', 'CASHOUT'].. Then what would the most efficient way to update the category dataframe such that index 0, 3, 4, 5 say 'bank' instead of the exact string extracted from details?

Comment: Yes you are right, but thats another question, I see this question as answered. Obviously feel free to post it as a new question and I will try to help you out :)

Comment: Ah, of course. I have opened a new question. Thanks so much. :)

Comment: Good, dont forget to [accept as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :) @geistmate

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `str.findall`

```
df['category']=df.details.str.findall('TRANSFER').str[0].fillna(0)
df
   amount          details  category
0  -68.23  PAYPAL TRANSFER  TRANSFER
1  -12.46     RALPHS #0079         0
2   -8.51   SAVE AS YOU GO         0
3   25.34    VENMO CASHOUT         0
4   -2.23  PAYPAL TRANSFER  TRANSFER
5  -64.29  PAYPAL TRANSFER  TRANSFER
```

If you have more than one string in `str_xfer` adding `'|'`

```
df.details.str.findall('TRANSFER|VENMO').str[0]
0    TRANSFER
1         NaN
2         NaN
3       VENMO
4    TRANSFER
5    TRANSFER
Name: details, dtype: object
```